# Move a robot head toward a 3D point

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working with a Kinect and two dynamixel motors (to have a pan/tilt).
I would like to send commands to the motors so that the kinect look at a point in 3D space.

I managed to have the Kinect look in a specified direction using the pan motor. But that was only in 2D space so I used Euler angles and trigonometry.
Using the same in 3D space would be much more complicated.

I would like to know if there are some tools to help doing such things ?
I heard that maybe using tf could help me but I don't know how I should do that.
Can someone help me ?

Thanks
Caroline

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60471/move-a-robot-head-toward-a-3d-point/) by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 395 on 2013-04-11

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephane.M](https://answers.ros.org/users/3548/stephane.m/) on 2013-04-11**:
As I understood, your kinect is fixed, and you can only turn it. So why would you change the 2D thing you already did ? As you can't go neerer from the point, finally, the distance of the point doesn't really matter, and you only need to turn you kinect left-right like you did up-down, no ?

**Comment by [CarolineQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/4109/carolineq/) on 2013-04-11**:
I can move the Kinect up-down and left-right. You are probably right and I could split the 3D problem into two 2D problems, but I thought there were simpler solutions for 3D problems like that, using directly 3D coordinates. Do you know things that could help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could have a look at how the PR2 does it: [pr2_head_action](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_head_action). Basically, they use [tf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf) to transform the 3D point into the pan and tilt frames, and then use two lines of trigonometry to get the corresponding pan and tilt angles.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-04-18**:
Also, I would suggest using the control_msgs/PointHeadAction message, as this is basically a new standard message derived from the pr2 version. See http://ros.org/wiki/control_msgs